# Error ORA-01843 NOT A VALID MONTH When Trying to Insert

Tags: java, oracle, date, gettext

I need to insert date from a `JTextField`, As following:

```
pst.setString (4, txt_date.getText());
```

But leaves the error:  ORA-01843 NOT A VALID MONTH

in oracle datatype is DATE (example: 5/30/2014)

How to solve this?

thanks

edit:

```
Connection conn = Connessione.ConnecrDb();
   Statement stmt = null;
   ResultSet emps = null;

   SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
String dateInString = "7-07-2014";

try {

       java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
    System.out.println(date);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I add this befor a     try { insert ...etc

Comment: How does your text returned from txt_date.getText() look like? You need to convert it to java.util.Date, java.sql.Date etc. in order to set the variable in preparedStatement.

Comment: Why yoiu don't use pst.setDate or pst.setTimestamp ?

Comment: @SebriZouhaier string cannot be converted to date. i have txtfield for get a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to format your string into date first like

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "7-07-2014";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Match your db format accordingly

```
txt_date.getText()
```

is a string value try using following code:

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
        String dateInString = txt_date.getText();

```
    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        pst.setDate (4, formatter.format(date)); 

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Or TimeStamp like:[HELP](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/)

```
pst.setTimestamp(java.util.Date().getTime());
```

Comment: not a valid month... i get data from a txtField, and after i click on save button and insert in to database oracle

Comment: Edited answer try this again

Comment: I solved. thanks. I use pst.setTimestamp(4, getCurrentTimeStamp()); that's fine too, as when a review is added, save the date and time that is saved. But I could not take the value from the txtField. otherwise I would have had to set the datatype to varchar2 and date. Thanks so much.